# Не получается авторизоваться

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                  .authorizeRequests()
                  .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                  .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                  .formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/login")
                  .permitAll()
                .and()
                  .logout()
                  .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password from user where email=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.email, ur.permissions from user u inner join user_permission ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.email=?");
    }
}
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Авторизация</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Ошибка
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    Выход из аккаунта - успешно!
</div>
<div class="content">
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> Email: <input type="text" name="email"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Пароль: <input type="text" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
    <a href="register">Рег. аккаунта</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Регистрация аккаунта проходит, все в базу забивается
Но при логине получается ошибка. login?error

Comment: А редирект куда-то есть в случае успешного логина?

Comment: @Wolframm нет, в случае успеха мне не вылезет ошибка же